# Working on swiftly dequeue a cell in UICollectionView - getting error in cellForItemAt trying to reuse the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Working on  swiftly dequeue a cell in UICollectionView

```
let cellClass: AnyClass = MyCell.self
var cellIdentifier: String { return String(describing: cellClass) }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.register(MyCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.titleLabel.text = cellType.properties.titleText
    cell.deviceImageView.image = cellType.properties.image
    return cell
}
```

Trying to avoid to cast the reused cell to an appropriate type.

Seeing the Error:

> Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'titleLabel'
>   Value of type 'UICollectionViewCell' has no member 'deviceImageView'

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the cast? You can't avoid it. Avoiding it is the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of `titleLabel` and `deviceImageView` lies in `MyCell`, but you are loading `UICollectionViewCell` by default.

You need to cast the collectionCell type to `MyCell`. Use `guard` statement in case not able to load `MyCell`:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCell else { fatalError("can not load MyCell") }

    cell.titleLabel.text = cellType.properties.titleText
    cell.deviceImageView.image = cellType.properties.image

    return cell
}
```

Comment: The use of guard for this is unnecessary. Simply force-cast the cell. If your app is setup incorrectly, it will crash (which you want to happen) and you can fix the mistake. In fact, the use of `guard` and `fatalError` is largely pointless. `guard` should be used to prevent a crash where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, We generally use it to debug errors at development type.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the cell with `as! MyCell` as `dequeueReusableCell` returns `UICollectionViewCell`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
    cell.titleLabel.text = cellType.properties.titleText
    cell.deviceImageView.image = cellType.properties.image
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast cell in your custom cell like this:

```
guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCell else {
            fatalError()
        }
cell.titleLabel.text = cellType.properties.titleText
cell.deviceImageView.image = cellType.properties.image
```

Comment: The use of `guard` for this is unnecessary. Simply force-cast the cell. If your app is setup incorrectly, it will crash (which you want to happen) and you can fix the mistake.